# Strange app icon duplication in pinned shortcut (Android O)

Tags: java, android, icons, shortcut, android-8.0-oreo

I'm creating a pinned shortcut of my app launcher icon for Android O device (either emulator or physical device) and found strange behaviour. My code looks like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createPinnedShortcut(Context context) {
        ShortcutManager shortcutManager = context.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
        if (shortcutManager != null) {
            if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
                Intent intent= MainActivity.getLaunchIntent(this);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "my_shortcut_id")
                        .setShortLabel(context.getString(R.string.my_app_description))
                        .setLongLabel(context.getString(R.string.my_app_long_description))
                        .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context, R.mipmap.my_app_icon))
                        .setIntent(intent)
                        .build();
                shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(shortcut, null);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(context, "Pinned shortcuts are not supported!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Everything works, but the launcher icon on the home screen is duplicated:

[image: app launcher icon]

There is a normal icon, but on right lower corner it placed yet another copy of the icon (about 30-40% smaller).

My icon resources are in `res/mipmap-*dpi*` folders

Any hints, clues?

**Update**

Answering to comments:

1) AndroidManifest under `./build/manifests/debug` looks like:

```
    <activity
        android:name="ru.ivanovpv.cellboxkeeper.android.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/cellboxkeeper"
        android:theme="@style/DefaultActivityTheme.Light"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <layout
            android:defaultHeight="800dp"
            android:defaultWidth="480dp"
            android:gravity="top|end"
            android:minHeight="320dp"
            android:minWidth="240dp" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> <!-- handle cbx files -->
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@mipmap/cellboxkeeper"
            android:label="@string/cellboxkeeper"
            android:logo="@mipmap/cellboxkeeper" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.cbx"
                android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter> 
        <!-- receive files from android share intent -->
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@mipmap/cellboxkeeper"
            android:label="@string/addToCellboxKeeper" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

2) There's not any folder like: `mipmap-*-v26`. Here's screenshot of folders in real apk. All icons in folders are normal (w/o duplication).

[image: folders]

Any other versions?

Comment: Could u please check the file "./build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml" and see how many times intent-filter tags are defined, should have only been defined in your main activity. Should be like: ..."android.intent.action.MAIN" />

Comment: Please share content of `mipmap-anydpi-v26` directory.

Comment: Please read update of question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution, key is attribute `android:logo`:

```
<intent-filter
        android:icon="@mipmap/cellboxkeeper"
        android:label="@string/cellboxkeeper"
        android:logo="@mipmap/cellboxkeeper" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

Deleting line with `android:logo` fixes duplication issue.

Hope, someone and sometimes will use and understands what's goin on

Comment: I don't have `android:logo` at all and still I got my Icon duplicated, any ideas why ?

Comment: Pinned shortcut creation generates ShortcutInfo which is used by the launcher app.
By default the launcher app uses special version of LauncherApps.getShortcutBadgedIconDrawable for generate the shortcut icon. 
This function creates the icon with the badge of the application which created the pinned shortcut. Therefore you can see this badge.
Currently you could not do anything with this.